# Python : writing numbers with constant number of characters before the comma

Tags: python, format, gif

I try to build a gif file (named say name) from some png documents (that I create myself) stocked in a common directory. The command I use from the Terminal is the following one :

convert -delay 2 -loop 0 *.png -scale 960x520 name.gif

The above command will use all the png files in the lexicographic order (this is the "*.png" part of the command), BUT my problem is that I can not manage to sort my files in the good way. All my files represent the graph of a function at some time t, so I named these files "t.png" where t ranges from 1 to 100, say ; so for example, the "file 1.png" comes AFTER "10.png" because "." comes after "0", and so on.

A way to solve it is to write every numbers t from 1 to 100 in the same format, say : 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 010, 011, 012, etc.
Namely, I want to use the same number of characters (here 3) to write the numbers t. As this t could range from 1 to an arbitrarily large integer, I'd prefer avoiding adding something in my code which would detect the number of character needed to write t and then add the remaining 0's. Besides, I'm convinced that there is a really simple way to write t as I would like to, even if I could not figured it out yet (nor I found something useful elsewhere).

If furthermore someone has another way to properly sort my graphs, he or she will be really welcome (I've tried for example to use the date of the creation of the files, as t smaller than t' implies that t.png had been created BEFORE t'.png, but here again no luck so far...).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this. First you can, as you suggest, put leading zeroes in the filenames. You can do that by formatting the number, like this:

```
>>> t = 32
>>> f"{t:03d}.png"
'032.png'
```

Note the `f` prefix to the format string. That is important. Leave it out and this will happen:

```
>>> "{t:03d}.png"
'{t:03d}.png'
```

If the interpreter complains about the `f` then you are using Python 3.6 or earlier and you need to do it this way instead:

```
>>> "{0:03d}.png".format(t)
'032.png'
```

The other way is to create your filenames as you have been doing but sort them afterwards into the order you want, by specifying the ordering rule in `key`:

```
>>> filelist = ["1.png","2.png","10.png","100.png"]
>>> sorted(filelist, key=lambda f: int(f.partition(".")[0]))
['1.png', '2.png', '10.png', '100.png']
```

rather than just taking the default sort order:

```
>>> sorted(filelist)
['1.png', '10.png', '100.png', '2.png']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'de have two questions.

1 : I save my files in a loop for, so my code contains the command savefig('re_gif/{j:08d}.png') where j ranges from 1 to 100 (j is the time t) ; problem now is that it saves only one file named {j:08d} in the directory re_gif ! How can I fix it ?

2. For the other way you propose, where should I type your command ? Python, Terminal ??

Comment: 1. You left out the `f` before the `"` in the string. That is why you get a file called {j:08d}. That `f` indicates an f-string and without it the `{ }` doesn't mean anything special.

Comment: 2. Those samples are Python code, typed into IDLE for checking. You would need to make a call to `sorted()` part of your Python program. You didn't present any code so it was hard to be specific.

Comment: Oh silly me ! I did not notice the `f` because my code was written in a different way (for sure, I should have written something in my original question). The interpreter ideed complained about the `f`, so thank you for having added the solution to this problem !
Now it works perfectly well, thank you very much !